# Django development server stops unexpectedly in Windows

Tags: django, windows, python-2.7, windows-10, django-1.8

I have Django application template based, which I am developing using Pycharm community. I am using Django built in development server to test my functionality in local Windows machine. The Django server stops at random when I am browsing the UI of the application. The same server is running fine in Ubuntu. The console doesn't give any error message at the time its stopping. The same happens but lesser when using --noreload flag while running. I tried in different machines also and the issue is same and if I should switch to some standard server then I need recommendation. Thank you in advance.

The stacks that I am using are:
Django - 1.8
Windows - 10
Python - 2.7 with virtualenv
Ubuntu - 18.04
Postgres - aws-rds postgres-11
Browsers - Chrome, Firefox, Edge

Comment: Does the same happen if you manually start the server from the command-line (using `python manage.py runserver`), instead of using pycharm?

Comment: Yes @dirkgroten